# Change attributes on view controller on alert selection (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to objective c and need some help. I've only one view controller which should show when as default an array called factbook. However I'd like to change the array by an alert validation. So that if the user would like to see sport he could just click on sport on the alert view and the current view controller would change the theme name to sport, the background color to the color scheme i'd like for the sport theme and the text to the sport facts array. Every help is welcome!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // init for displaying facts
    self.factBook = [[FactBook alloc] init];
    self.colorWheel = [[ColorWheel alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [self.colorWheel randomColor];
    self.funFactLabel.text = [self.factBook randomFact];
}

- (IBAction)showFunFact:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [self.colorWheel randomColor];
    funFactLabel.text = [self.factBook randomFact];
}

- (IBAction)changeTheme:(UIButton *)sender {
    // to sport
    [changeThemeNotification addButton:@"change to sport" validationBlock:^BOOL{
      BOOL passedValidation = true;
      return passedValidation;
    } actionBlock:^{
      // segue to sport
      self.themeName.text = @"Sport";
      self.sportFactBook = [[SportFactBook alloc] init];
      self.sportColorWheel = [[SportColorWheel alloc] init];

// not working 
//      self.funFactLabel = [self.sportFactBook randomSportFact];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [self.sportColorWheel randomColor];
    }];            
    //...
}
```

Comment: what is `changeThemeNotification`?

Comment: a button on a view controller which if clicked shows an alert to change the theme

Comment: did you subclass `NSButton` and add the selector `addButton: validationBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this comment

```
  // not working 
  //      self.funFactLabel = [self.sportFactBook randomSportFact];
```

is the part you want to fix.  If you are updating a label, just change its text

```
 self.funFactLabel.text = [self.sportFactBook randomSportFactText];
```

`randomSportFactText` should return an `NSString*`.

If you set the output to a new label object, that doesn't update the view -- it just disassociates the outlet from the label in the view.

If you want to change just the `backgroundColor`, you can do that too:

```
 self.funFactLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Your solution worked fine for the first time. Unfortunately i don't know how to do that what you described in your last sentence.

Comment: You don't want to do that -- that's why your code doesn't work.  Don't reset outlets (unless you really know what you are doing).  Just update the label that's there by using its properties.

Comment: and how do i use the sport fact array more than one time? At the moment it is like i'd added it to the view did load.

Comment: I don't know what "sport fact array" means.

Comment: sorry. just that this self.funFactLabel.text = [self.sportFactBook randomSportFactText]; works not only once

Comment: I'm sorry -- don't understand. What does "working" and "not working" mean exactly.  What did it do and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on that line?  Does it get there every time? Does it call the random text function? Does that function return something different each time?

Comment: Ok. Your solution worked really fine as i change the category to sport. But if you try to see more facts it doesn't work. So this self.funFactLabel.text = [self.sportFactBook randomSportFactText]; only works for the first time. Do you have a idea how to use this every time? Sorry for this bad exploitation.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on that line? YES. Does it get there every time? SURE. Does it call the random text function? YES. Does that function return something different each time? YES. This particular code just runs once.